# How to get the unique id (key) of a document in Firebase database collection?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch the documents of a collection in my React-Native app but I dont know how to fetch them by ID (key). 
P.S: I dont have any field called unique id or id inside the document but as I have understood, the unique id is the auto-generated key when I create a document which stands as the name of that document (20 characters id).

This is how I fetch all the fields inside a document:

```
  var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('discounts')
            .orderBy('rest_id')
```

**EDIT**:

```
getDiscounts = () => {
    try {
        this.setState({
            loading: true
        })

        var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('discounts')
            .orderBy('rest_id')
            .limit(this.state.limit)

        ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot => {
            var discounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(document => document.data());

            var lastVisibleDiscount = discounts[discounts.length - 1].rest_id;
            this.setState({
                discounts: discounts,
                lastVisibleDiscount: lastVisibleDiscount,
                loading: false,
            });
        }));

    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print the keys of the documents in the collection in the order of the value of their `rest_id` field, you can do something like this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("discounts").orderBy('rest_id').get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id);
    });
});
```

This is an almost literal copy of the code in the documentation on [getting all documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection), so I recommend spending some time there.

Comment: Hey man, it doesn't work as I wanted. I can get the id now but I cant get the data as before, they dont show on the view after I add your code. any idea?

Comment: You can get the data through `doc.data()`.  But to know why it doesn't work for you, we'd need to see the minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem. I highly recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then opening a new question with precisely that information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use (using await/async)

```
const ref = await ref.get()
```

It will have an array called docs that you can map over to get the id and data of the document:

```
const data = ref.docs.map(doc => {return {id: doc.id, data: doc.data()} })
```

Comment: how can I add the ID and DATA to the same object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. If you mean to not have a nested object with data, it is as simple as using spread notation in the return statement `{id: doc.id, data: doc.data()}`, so you'll end up with `{id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}`